# function not works in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am having problems with my code . 
 Nothing happen the function f and g are not called, i just want to pass the array into a function and do stuff with it :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script lang="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //   l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i  remove the comment it works
           function f(E) {


               l = prompt("Your name :");
               E["Name"] = l;
               l = prompt("Your Age :");
               E["Age"] = l;
               l = prompt("Your Note :");
               E["Note"] = l;

           }
         // l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i remove the comment it works
          function g(E) {
               for (ind in E) {

                   document.write("E[" + ind + "]=" + E[ind]);
               }
           }
           E = newarray(3);
           //l = prompt("Your name :"); // here if i remove the comment nothing happen
           f(E);
           g(E);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is using a function called `newarray`, which isn't defined anywhere in the code you've shown. If you look in your web console, you'll see a nice, clear error message, pointing to the line that failed.

Comment: "Nothing happen" is not quite right  (also grammatically ;-)) - there is an error in your code preventing further execution. You should look at the JS-Console (different ways to access it depending on the browser) to see the err-msg....

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an array at all, you want an object. You can create an object using an object initializer:

```
E = {};
```

---

Side note 1: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) all over the place. You need to declare your variables.

---

Side note 2; Using `document.write` after the main parsing of the page is complete (for instance, after `prompt`) will implicitly call `document.open`, which will completely wipe out your page. If you want to add to the page, use the DOM.

---

Here's an example with various issues in the code cleaned up, including variable naming and function naming — meaningful names are useful for you, and useful for people trying to help you:

```js
function getData() {
  var data = {};
  data.Name = prompt("Your name :");
  data.Age = prompt("Your Age :");
  data.Note = prompt("Your Note :");
  return data;
}

function showData(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    display("E[" + key + "]=" + data[key]);
  }
}

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

var d = getData();
showData(d);
```

Comment: Please can you tell me why i cant use document.write ?

Comment: @cip: I did: *"Using `document.write`...will implicitly call `document.open`, which will completely wipe out your page..."* By "wipe out" I mean it will remove all of the content on the page and replace it. I suppose your current page doesn't have any content, so that would be okay, but in general `document.write` after the main parsing is done is a no-no. (Some argue it's *always* a no-no.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Array(3)` instead of `newarray(3)` :

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script lang="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //   l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i  remove the comment it works
           function f(E) {


               l = prompt("Your name :");
               E["Name"] = l;
               l = prompt("Your Age :");
               E["Age"] = l;
               l = prompt("Your Note :");
               E["Note"] = l;

           }
         // l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i remove the comment it works
          function g(E) {
               for (ind in E) {

                   document.write("E[" + ind + "]=" + E[ind]);
               }
           }
           E = new Array(3);
           //l = prompt("Your name :"); // here if i remove the comment nothing happen
           f(E);
           g(E);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here you would want to use object instead of array.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script lang="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //   l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i  remove the comment it works
           function f(E) {


               E["Name"] = prompt("Your name :");
               E["Age"] = prompt("Your Age :");
               E["Note"]  = prompt("Your Note :");

           }
         // l = prompt("Your name :"); // if i remove the comment it works
          function g(E) {
               for (ind in E) {

                   document.write("E[" + ind + "]=" + E[ind]);
               }
           }
           var E = {};
           //l = prompt("Your name :"); // here if i remove the comment nothing happen
           f(E);
           g(E);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Except the OP doesn't actually want an array at all, nor is there any reason to give it a length of 3 when it's not being used to store anything at indexes 0, 1, or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

First it should be E = new Array(3);
Since E is a global variable (and used in your first function), it is best to declare it before your first function.
While it is not necessary, it would be helpful with debugging to give each of your prompts their own variable name.